# Find the standard matrix for the linear transformation T?

Tags: linear-algebra

> T is the clockwise rotation ($\alpha$ is negative) of 30$^o$ in $R^2$,
>   v=(2,1). Then find the image of the vector v.

I'm bit confused with this problem as I tried with different methods even the lecture notes but I'm confused. Can someone please help me out? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to the comments: the standard rotation matrix in $2D$ **counter-clockwise** by an angle of $\theta$ is
$$R=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin(-\theta)\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}.$$
To rotate clockwise is to rotate in the opposite direction to counter-clockwise, which prompts that a rotation of $\alpha$ clockwise is a rotation of $-\alpha$ counter-clockwise.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Look up (anywhere) the matrix of this rotation $T$, and multiply it by the *column vector* $v^T=\pmatrix{2\\1}$ from the right.

The point is that, if $[T]$ denotes the matrix of a linear map $T$ then we have
$$[T]\cdot u\ =\ T(u)$$
for every (column) vector $u$.

Comment: I did, but I'm having bit trouble dealing with the fact which says "$\alpha$ is negative" thats where I got lost. Would you mind explaining how to deal with that?

Comment: @Tharindu If $\theta$ is the counter clockwise rotation (standard), then $\alpha=-\theta$ is the clockwise rotation.

Comment: @Daryl Correct me if I'm wrong then the T={$\sin(30-\alpha),\cos(30-\alpha)$} right?